# How do you replace multiple elements in a string with other elements efficiently?

Tags: python, string

Given a string, say 'ABCD' and you are supposed to replace 'A' and 'C' with 'E' and 'J'. How would you replace this and return the output as a string in python?

Comment: Please review the edits made. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Using the replace() method

```
string = 'ABCD'
#Use dictionary of characters to be replaced
chars_to_replace = {
    'A':'E',
    'C':'J'
}
for key, value in chars_to_replace.items():
    # Use the replace() method
    string = string.replace(key, value)
print(string)
```

Using a for loop

```
string = "ABCD"
chars_to_replace = {
    'A':'E',
    'C':'J'
}
new_string = ''
# Use for loop to iterate over all chars in string
for i in string:
    # Check if character is in dict key
    if i in chars_to_replace.keys():
        # If yes, replace values of those chars
        # and add to new_string
        new_string += chars_to_replace[i]
    else:
        # If not, just add them to new_string
        new_string += i
print(new_string)
```

Comment: Best way of doing this is with `str.translate()` method. Concatenating strings in for-loop should be avoided. Also no need for iteration manually.

Answer (score 0):

Use [str.translate()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.translate) method :

```
string = 'ABCD'
m = str.maketrans({'A': 'E', 'C': 'J'})

print(string.translate(m))
```

output :

```
EBJD
```